# Why won't jQuery eval the response from ajax script when status code is failure

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax request with `data-type: 'script'`.

If the response's status code is 200, the returned javascript gets executed fine. If it is an error code like 500 or 403, no execution takes place.

I've re-read the doc 3 times:

> "script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain
>   text. ...

This doesn't state it is conditional on success or any other condition.

As my server is responding with a response type of "text/javascript", I would have assumed that jQuery would handle that content type (i.e. evaluate it) even if it responded with a '500' status code (i.e. "hey, I couldn't do what you asked me to do")

Is this an issue with jQuery? Or is this the expected behavior and the documentation is incomplete?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. Why would it try to execute something with status 500 or 403? It should assume the server failed to respond with a script.

Comment: *'There is no "on success" or any other condition.'* - What do you mean? In jQuery, you can define "success" and "error" handlers for any Ajax request.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Edited my question for clarity. My understanding is that `$.getScript` is just a shortcut for the general `$.ajax`. Please note that it works fine unless I change the status code of the response.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune, all ajax requests will not continue with parsing/evaluating unless the status is one that implies that the requested returned what it was asked for.. All statuses that imply a failure stop the processing of the ajax and call the respective fail handlers. You do get the returned data, though, even on failed requests throught the `.error` callback or `.fail` deferred method.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thanks. Can you point out where that's stated in the doc?

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune, it is not stated so explicitly in the docs. But, it does make sense (*at least to me*)

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.5 ajax calls return a deferred object.

So you can use

```
$.ajax({/*options*/})
  .done(function(data, status, jqxhr){ alert("$.ajax completed!"); })
  .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception){ alert("$.ajax failed!"); });
```

***note** the actual script will be evaluated before the `.done` method is called, when a successful request occurs*